# Is it possible to change how my internet router responds to certain requests/urls?

Tags: dns, request, response, router, firewall

Yeah, I was wondering if for example, when any device using my routers internet makes a request to a certain url, my internet will respond to it with a response that I set for it, similar to how something like Fiddler works.

I have an Xfinity router and wanted to know if this is possible and how it can be done, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to override DNS resolution at your router level. Or add filter to your router for certian domain names.